# Swift Action Extension NSString error?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, option-type

I am new to Swift! So I am building an action extension in Swift and an error appears

```
itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypePropertyList as NSString, options: nil, completionHandler: { [unowned self] (result: NSSecureCoding!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

The error seems to be at the NSString. The error reads:

'NSString' is not simplicity convertible to 'String': did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert

I change it the NSString to

```
kUTTypePropertyList as String
```

I get another error saying:

Cannot convert value of type '(NSSecureCoding!, NSError!) -> Void to expected argument type 'NSItemProviderCompletionHandler?'

How do I solve this error? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, `NSItemProviderCompletionHandler` is defined as `(NSSecureCoding?, NSError!) -> Void`, but you've used `(NSSecureCoding!, NSError!) -> Void`.

On `result`, simply change your `!` to `?` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swift 3 syntax. it changes to :

> typealias CompletionHandler = (NSSecureCoding?, Error!) -> Void

**NSError** -> **Error**